# cyclonedxBom gradle plugin is not analyzing my dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, byte-order-mark

My problem is the following...
I'm trying to use the gradle plugin here https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gradle-plugin for generating a bom in the cyclonedx format. I will need it for pushing it into dependency track and analyze my dependencies.
However i'm stuck because, with the command ./gradlew app:cyclonedxBom, I obtain my bom.xml file, but this one does not present infos about the dependencies in my project.

I'm working on an android project in android studio with the following build.gradle:

---

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.cyclonedx.bom' version '1.6.1'
}

cyclonedxBom {
    includeConfigs += ["compileClasspath"]
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.demo_android_app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo_android_app"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.arakhne.afc.core:maths:17.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

---

and I obtain the following bom ...

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bom serialNumber="urn:uuid:9032eac7-fbf1-44cf-95fe-4f41f0da7f96" version="1" xmlns="http://cyclonedx.org/schema/bom/1.4">
  <metadata>
    <timestamp>2023-05-24T14:21:16Z</timestamp>
    <tools>
      <tool>
        <vendor>CycloneDX</vendor>
        <name>cyclonedx-gradle-plugin</name>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
      </tool>
    </tools>
    <component type="library" bom-ref="pkg:maven/demo-android-app/app@unspecified">
      <group>demo-android-app</group>
      <name>app</name>
      <version>unspecified</version>
      <purl>pkg:maven/demo-android-app/app@unspecified</purl>
    </component>
  </metadata>
</bom>
```

As you can see, there aren't informations about the dependencies.

I ve tried also to change my configs for the plugin as the README in the repo of the plugin says, but I have not found solutions anyway.

```
cyclonedxBom {
    // includeConfigs is the list of configuration names to include when generating the BOM (leave empty to include every configuration)
    includeConfigs = ["runtimeClasspath"]
    // skipConfigs is a list of configuration names to exclude when generating the BOM
    skipConfigs = ["compileClasspath", "testCompileClasspath"]
    // skipProjects is a list of project names to exclude when generating the BOM
    skipProjects = [rootProject.name, "yourTestSubProject"]
    // Specified the type of project being built. Defaults to 'library'
    projectType = "application"
    // Specified the version of the CycloneDX specification to use. Defaults to '1.4'
    schemaVersion = "1.4"
    // Boms destination directory. Defaults to 'build/reports'
    destination = file("build/reports")
    // The file name for the generated BOMs (before the file format suffix). Defaults to 'bom'
    outputName = "bom"
    // The file format generated, can be xml, json or all for generating both. Defaults to 'all'
    outputFormat = "json"
    // Exclude BOM Serial Number. Defaults to 'true'
    includeBomSerialNumber = false
    // Exclude License Text. Defaults to 'true'
    includeLicenseText = false
    // Override component version. Defaults to the project version
    componentVersion = "2.0.0"
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: please ask the official support channel: https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gradle-plugin/issues

Comment: @jko: I think it is probably fine to direct folks to the Issues page on GitHub, as long as it is done in comments. That said, there may be value in letting people ask here - not least that more people will see the questions. Shall core devs of this plugin not answer questions on Stack Overflow?